# bot.py will not run Traceback bot.run(TOKEN)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, discord.py

The bot was up and running a couple of weeks ago, I checked on it today and realised it was offline. I tried to run it again and this error message hit me. Have not done any changes since the last time it was running...

**Error message from console:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 347, in <module>
    bot.run(TOKEN)
  File "C:\Users\bjha0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 640, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\bjha0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 621, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bjha0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 585, in start
    await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\bjha0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 499, in connect
    await self._connect()
  File "C:\Users\bjha0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 463, in _connect
    await self.ws.poll_event()
  File "C:\Users\bjha0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 471, in poll_event
    await self.received_message(msg)
  File "C:\Users\bjha0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 425, in received_message
    func(data)
  File "C:\Users\bjha0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\state.py", line 750, in parse_guild_create
    guild = self._get_create_guild(data)
  File "C:\Users\bjha0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\state.py", line 725, in _get_create_guild
    guild._from_data(data)
  File "C:\Users\bjha0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 297, in _from_data
    self._sync(guild)
  File "C:\Users\bjha0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 328, in _sync
    self._add_channel(CategoryChannel(guild=self, data=c, state=self._state))
  File "C:\Users\bjha0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\channel.py", line 726, in __init__
    self._update(guild, data)
  File "C:\Users\bjha0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\channel.py", line 737, in _update
    self._fill_overwrites(data)
  File "C:\Users\bjha0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 294, in _fill_overwrites
    self._overwrites.append(_Overwrites(id=overridden_id, **overridden))
TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'deny_new'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just fixed this error myself its because a new version of discord.py has been relased so just install it (pip uninstall discord.py, pip install discord.py)

Comment: No problem my freind

Answer (score 0):

Discord updated their system. Now they drop the support of discordapp.com domain.

The solution is:

```
$ sudo pip3 uninstall discord.py
$ sudo pip3 install discord.py
```

P. S. you need sudo if you do not have root permissions

The new version of this library refers to discord.com domain now.

Comment: I'm running windows not Ubuntu, but I understood what the problem was. Thanks!